# How to add Maven and ProGuard to android application

Tags: java, android, maven, android-proguard

I am trying to incorporate the Google Direction Library created by https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-GoogleDirectionLibrary

In the README it shows the following downloads. I know how to add gradle dependencies, but what does adding proguard and maven do and how do I add it?

[Maven](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3jne.png)

[Proguard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcImQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the dependency either via Maven OR Gradle. So if you're using Gradle, that's 100% fine and just do that.

As for Proguard, there should be a file called "proguard-rules.pro" or something like that in your project. Simply copy the text from the Github page and paste it into that file in your project.

That's it.